# EditText Android Studio

Tags: android

Tenho Seguinte EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/textSenha"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:hint = "@string/senha"
    android:textCursorDrawable = "@drawable/cursor"
    android:backgroundTint = "@color/black"
    android:inputType = "textCapWords"/>
```

[image: seguinte resutado:]
minha pergunta seguinte, como faço para ficar dessa forma? Usuário selecionar campo senha hint ele sofre `elevation`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer um *wrap* do seu `EditText` com um `TextInputLayout` ( [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) ).

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="hint"
      android:id="@+id/editText1" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Para manter compatibilidade seria bom utilizar a *[design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)*.
 Adicione no *graddle*

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```